# Does the scanf empty the buffer after reading the input data (in C)?

Tags: c, scanf, buffering

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    int a,b;
    int i;
    
    setbuf(stdin, buf);
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    
    for(i=0; buf[i]!='\n'; i++){
        putchar(buf[i]);  
    }
    
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

When I input the values `1 2`, I used `setbuf` to find out if the buffer was really cleared after reading the values.
When I printed out the `buf`, however, the value I entered remained the same in `buf`. That is, the output was `1 2`

Why is this happening? 
I would really appreciate if you could answer.

Comment: What would a "cleared" state look like?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I think the value of buf[0] should be '\n'

Comment: The buffer is for `scanf` (and other stdio functions) to use, not you.  It's not defined what will be in the buffer, and it's not meaningful to look and see.

Comment: Allocating `char buf[1024]` is not correct.  It should be `char buf[BUFSIZ]`.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is "no".  stdin buffers are not cleared as they are read.  The stdio functions typically maintain a pointer into the buffer, tracking the position of the next character to be read.  Only when all the characters in the buffer have been used up is another batch of input data read in to the buffer, overwriting what was there previously.  (I'm describing a "typical" implementation, but again, there are few or no guarantees.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: `char buf[BUFSIZ];` would also not be correct. It should be `static char buf[BUFSIZ];`, as the lifetime of the buffer must be at least as long as the lifetime of the stream. See [footnote 273 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note273). The [documentation on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setbuf) also points this out.

Comment: @SteveSummit, want to post that?

Comment: @DanielWalker No, but if you want to, feel free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what the C Standard says about function `setbuf`:

> **7.21.5.5 The `setbuf` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> void setbuf(FILE * restrict stream,
>             char * restrict buf);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> Except that it returns no value, the `setbuf` function is equivalent to the `setvbuf` function invoked with the values `_IOFBF` for `mode` and `BUFSIZ` for `size`, or (if `buf` is a null pointer), with the value `_IONBF` for `mode`.
>
> **Returns**
> The `setbuf` function returns no value.

> **7.21.5.6 The `setvbuf` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int setvbuf(FILE * restrict stream,
>             char * restrict buf,
>             int mode, size_t size);
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> The `setvbuf` function may be used only after the stream pointed to by `stream` has been associated with an open file and before any other operation (other than an unsuccessful call to `setvbuf`) is performed on the stream. The argument `mode` determines how stream will be buffered, as follows: `_IOFBF` causes input/output to be fully buffered; `_IOLBF` causes input/output to be line buffered; `_IONBF` causes input/output to be unbuffered. If `buf` is not a null pointer, the array it points to may be used instead of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function<sup>277)</sup> and the argument `size` specifies the size of the array; otherwise, `size` may determine the size of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function. The contents of the array at any time are indeterminate.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `setvbuf` function returns zero on success, or nonzero if an invalid value is given for `mode` or if the request cannot be honored.

---

<sup>277) The buffer has to have a lifetime at least as great as the open stream, so the stream should be closed before a buffer that has automatic storage duration is deallocated upon block exit.</sup>

It follows that:

- The array `buf` in your code should have a length of `BUFSIZ`, which can be different from `1024`.
- This array should not have automatic storage class because `stdin` is not closed before the function `main` returns. It should be defined as `static char buf[BUFSIZ];`
- the buffer may or may not be used by the stream handling functions.
- *The contents of the array at any time are indeterminate*, hence nothing can be expected about the buffer contents: you observe that the user input is present, but this is not guaranteed. Most implementations have pointers or offsets in the `FILE` structure to keep track of used and available portions of the buffer.
- It is highly unlikely that stream handling functions *clear* the buffer contents after reading the bytes, because it would require reloading the buffer from the file in case of seeking back over previous contents, but again there is no guarantee about this either.

`setbuf` is a legacy function with limited use, `setvbuf` is preferred to select the buffering mode and buffer size, in the rare cases where it may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Collating what is found in the comments, there's no guarantee that the libc implementation will clear the `stdin` buffer.  The `FILE` structure could just keep a pointer to its current position within the buffer.

In addition, you need to change the size of the buffer to `BUFSIZ` and make it so that its lifetime is for the rest of the program.  According to the [C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note273):

> The buffer has to have a lifetime at least as great as the open stream, so the stream should be closed before a buffer that has automatic storage duration is deallocated upon block exit.

This can be accomplished by either making the buffer global or declaring it to be [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration):

```c
static char buf[BUFSIZ];
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that if [`setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf) is used instead of `setbuf`, then the size of the buffer can also be changed.